# Getting curly braces in output - GCM send multiple data

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send data to device with GCM but getting curly braces in output(as below image). I'm new to php and I wonder how to fix this issue. Here is the part of PHP server code :

```
 public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message, $title) {
    // include config
    include_once './config.php';


    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$data = array("title" => $title, "message" => $message);
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $data
    );

   $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

/////////

I changed the `send_message.php` like this and it fixed.

```
if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"]) && isset($_GET["title"])) {
$regId = $_GET["regId"];
$messagem = $_GET["message"];
$titlem = $_GET["title"];

include_once './GCM.php';

$gcm = new GCM();

$registatoin_ids = array($regId);
$message = array("message" => $messagem);
$title = array($titlem);


$result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $messagem, $titlem);

echo $result;`
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you post your client code that displays the notification?

Comment: Then please write an answer and accept it, so that people would know this question has been resolved.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, however with the some specific values in the data field. The weird part is that it only happens sometimes

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: sorry, with JSON GCM payload data should be an assoc array. Mixed up with an older flavor of the protocol. That said, what is your intent on the Android side like?

EDIT: dump the whole extra bundle.

```
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
for(String k : b.keySet())
    Log.d("tag", k + "=" + b.get(k).toString());
```

Comment: I'm using PendingIntent and getting data like this : `intent.getStringExtra("message");`

Comment: For example when I changed the code from server `array("title" => $title, "message" => $message);` to this : `array("title" => 'titleTextHere', "message" => 'messageTextHEre');`, it send the multiple datas perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

edited:

ok, I think your problem is you're posting the value {.....} with no key.  it's like saying

http://..... com?{myjson:"stuff"}

I haven't reviewed the api, but it seems it should be something like post "data=".json_encode($fields);

Comment: It was working succesfully with $message variable until I added the $title variable. I followed this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/